# git latexdiff struggles with symbolic link to references bib file

Tags: latexdiff

I'm using `git latexdiff --latexmk --main my-dissertation.tex first-submission-tag HEAD` to keep track of my dissertation corrections after my viva.  It's working really well (I'm so grateful for this tool), but I have one problem: all the citations cannot be found, e.g.

```
Citation 'xcsp3comp2022' on page 17 undefined on input line 1526.
```

I think this might be because my `references.bib` is actually a symbolic link to `../literature/zotero_library.bib`.  I used Zotero as my reference manager with "Better BibTeX" auto-export.  The `../literature` directory is also in the same github repository so has been version-controlled throughout my thesis writing.

Is there any kind of workaround, e.g. for latexdiff to treat the symlink `references.bib` as untracked?  I saw the `--ln-untracked` option but my symlink is under git control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I got help from the git-latexdiff project author [here](https://gitlab.com/git-latexdiff/git-latexdiff/-/issues/72).

The suggestion (which works for me) is to use `--whole-tree`.